# How to fresh install Win7 under grub boot loader?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2

I am new with Linux and my laptop has Ubuntu 12.10 and Win7/64bit. Grub boot loader makes me choose which to boot at startup. I want to clean re-install of Win7 without changing configuration of GRUB and UBUNTU. Is it possible? If possible please how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general outline:

Reinstalling Windows 7
Reinstate GRUB
Mount the /boot partition
Install the boot loader

Step One
Re-install Win7.

Step Two
Load up from your Ubuntu live CD, and then run these commands.

If you DO NOT have a separate /boot partition:

> sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /mnt
>   sudo rm -rf /boot    # Careful here, make sure YOU ARE USING THE LIVE CD. I tried it, it works.
>   sudo ln -s /mnt/boot /boot

If you have a SEPARATE /boot partition:

> sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /boot

Step Four
Then continue with those commands:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-pc
>   sudo grub-setup /dev/sda     # NOTE THAT THERE IS NO DIGIT
>   sudo umount /boot

And restart. It should work fine and boot both systems.

Answer (score -1):

install Grub Customizer and Boot Repair:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer boot-repair

Comment: I don't think this is of any help to the question here. The installation of Windows will simply overwrite Grub with a customizer installed or not.